# 'calcCharge' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, function

I need to create an ADT for an assignment. I have my class definition in a header file as follows:

```
#ifndef PHONECALL_H
#define PHONECALL_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class PhoneCall
{
public:
    PhoneCall();
    PhoneCall(string newNumber); 
    ~PhoneCall(); 


    string getNumber()const;
    int getLength()const;
    float getRate()const;

    float calcCharge(); //calcuates total cost of call

    friend bool operator==(const PhoneCall & call1, const PhoneCall & call2);

    friend istream& operator >>(istream& in, PhoneCall& call); 
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, const PhoneCall& call); 


private:
    string number; 
    int length; 
    float rate; 
};
```

All the bodies of the functions are in the implementation file (no errors there)
Then in the main application file, when I call the `calcCharge()` function, I get:

> error: 'calcCharge()' was not declared in this scope

This is the only error I get. Here is the application file code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "PhoneCall.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string num, cellNum;
int length;
float rate, total;

cout << "Enter a phone number: " << endl;
cin>> num;

PhoneCall theCall(num);

ifstream read;

while (read >> cellNum >> length >> rate)
{
    if (cellNum == num)
    {
        total += calcCharge();
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

I know the code for the main application is incomplete, but due to this error I am not able to test whether the program is doing what I need it to do.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as a simple error not useful to others.

Comment: You really ought to avoid `using namespace std` - it is a bad habit to get into, and [can silently change the meaning of your program](/q/1452721) when you're not expecting it.  Get used to using the namespace prefix (`std` is intentionally very short), or importing *just the names you need* into the *smallest reasonable scope*.  It's especially pernicious in header files, as you now inflict the problem on every source file that includes the header!

Comment: Oh, and you only need `<iosfwd>` for the header - that's much lighter-weight than `<iostream>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a member of the class.

```
total += theCall.calcCharge();
```